# How to retrieve all the values associated with a key?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to get all the values associated with a key in Map.
For e.g,

```
Map tempMap = new HashMap();
tempMap.put("1","X");
tempMap.put("2","Y");
tempMap.put("3","Z");
tempMap.put("1","ABC");
tempMap.put("2","RR");
tempMap.put("1","RT");
```

How to retrieve all the values associated with key 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
tempMap.put("1", new LinkedList<String>());
tempMap.get("1").add("X");
tempMap.get("1").add("Y");
tempMap.get("1").add("Z");

for(String value : tempMap.get("1")) {
  //do something
}
```

This compartmentalizes values that correspond to the key "1" into their own list, which you can easily access. Just don't forget to initialize the list... else `NullPointerException`s will come to get you.

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 7):

the thing you must understand is that in a Map, the key is unique.

that means that after

```
tempMap.put("1","X");
```

"1" is mapped to "X"

and after

```
tempMap.put("1","ABC");
```

"1" is mapped to "ABC" and the previous value ("X") is lost

Comment: @Anand: if you need to map the same key to several Strings, use a Collection as the value. I.e., define your map something like this: Map<String, Collection<String>> tempMap.

Answer (score 5):

From the HashMap javadoc:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value **is replaced**.

Answer (score 3):

can't

try using [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)'s Multimap

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing something important:

```
Map tempMap = new HashMap();
tempMap.put("1","X");
tempMap.put("2","Y");
tempMap.put("3","Z");
tempMap.put("1","ABC"); // replaces "X"
tempMap.put("2","RR"); // replaces "Y"
tempMap.put("1","RT"); // replaces "ABC"
```

Also, you should use generics where possible, so your first line should be:

```
Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to associate each key with a Set of values, with corresponding logic to create the set and enter/remove values from it instead of simple put() and get() on the Map.

Or you can use one of the readymade Multimap implementations such as the [one in Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html).